# Why is Rabin-Karp algo seemingly less efficient than brute force algo for string matching

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, string-matching, rabin-karp

I am just looking at various algorithm's efficiency. Not just big O efficiency, but practical efficiency. Anyway i was testing a Rabin Karp algorithm i wrote against a brute force string comparison approach, and the brute force approach almost consistently was twice as fast. Why is this? I thought that a rolling hash was suppose to be much more efficient.

My only guess on why this is is that must rabin Karp solution just sucks, but otherwise im not too sure. I've tested it on very large strings (400kb) and the results are always the same.

An example is for a 400kb string

- brute force - 0.023785114288330078 seconds
- rabin karp - 0.041351318359375 seconds

The code for both are below:

```html
def rabinKarp(self, inpStr, containStr) -> bool:
        if len(containStr) > len(inpStr):
            return False
    
        searchHash = 0
        d, p = 52, 2**16 + 7
        for i in containStr:
            searchHash = (searchHash * d + ord(i)) % p
        
        currHash = 0
        
        # init currHash
        for i in range(0, len(containStr)):
            currHash = (currHash * d + ord(inpStr[i])) % p
        
        h =  d ** (len(containStr) - 1)
        for i in range(len(containStr), len(inpStr)):
            if currHash == searchHash:
                return True
            currHash = (currHash - ord(inpStr[i - len(containStr)]) * h) % p
            currHash = (currHash * d + ord(inpStr[i])) % p
        
        return False
```

```html
def program(self, stringInp, matchInp):
        if len(matchInp) > len(stringInp):
            return False
        
        for i in range(len(matchInp), len(stringInp) + 1):
            if stringInp[i - len(matchInp): i] == matchInp:
                return True
        
        return False
```

I am just asking out of personal curiosity.

Comment: how big is your `matchInp` and `stringInp` ? can you test for bunch of small strings and report their timings for each. moreover algo questions are better suited for  cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I tested a string length of 10 characters to a 400KB string. Results where the same for all. For a small string, i got the following results. Rabin Karp - 2.7179718017578125e-05 seconds and brute force -  2.2172927856445312e-05

Comment: my guess is it might be due to python's optimizations. Python is probably not the best language to compare performance of two algorithms as there are lots of things going on behind the hood. If you get similar difference for exact same code in c/c++ as well then I guess it's worth diving into.

Comment: Your rabinKarp implementation doesn't work when the pattern being sought is at the end of the string. i,e., rabinKarp("abc", "bc") returns False

Comment: The brute force implementation exhibits unusual behaviour: the performance is sublinear w.r.t. the length of matchInp. At the first glance, if your input is say `'a'*M` and your output is `'a'*N+'b'` you would have run time roughly proportional to `M*N`. But this doesn't happen IME. Increasing N 100-fold increases execution time by a factor of only 2 or 3. I have no idea what might be the reason of it.